# Laravel Homestead won't start, always enters 'guru meditation' status

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, digital-ocean, homestead

I am trying to run [Laravel Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead) box on DigitalOcean's Ubuntu 14.04 LEMP droplet. I'm following these two tutorials:

- [How to install Vagrant on a VPS Running Ubuntu 12.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-vagrant-on-a-vps-running-ubuntu-12-04)
- [Laravel Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead)

But I can't seem to start up the box after the installation. I keep getting this error message:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: homestead
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 => 22280 (adapter 1)
    default: 443 => 22443 (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 => 23306 (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 => 25432 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'gurumeditation' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.
```

Here is my VirtualBox's error log:

- [VirtualBox log](http://www.datafilehost.com/get.php?file=4c47075c)

---

Comment: Were you able to fix this? What was you solution?

Comment: Not really, at least not on Digital Ocean. But I found out why this happens. It's because the host machine does not support so-called hardware virtualization, or the hardware virtualization option is disabled in the host machine's bios. Homestead is a 64-bit image, and it needs hardware virtualization enabled. I could install it on my local machine, but not on Digital Ocean. I'm guessing that any other 32-bit image would work, but didn't have time to experiment. If you make any progress on this, please let me know.